# Prove an $n\times n$ matrix is negative definite

Tags: matrices

I wonder is there any way to prove the $n\times n$ matrix with elements below is negative definite:

$$ \sigma_{ij} = \frac{a_ia_j}{\sum_k s_ka_k} \space;  i \neq j \text{ (off diagonal  terms)}$$
$$\sigma_{ii} = \frac{a_ia_i}{\sum_k s_ka_k} - \frac{a_i}{s_i} \text{ (diagonal  terms)}$$

Here $1\leq i,j,k\leq n$, $0 < a_i < 1$ and $s_k$ is the weight of $a_k$ such that:
$0 < s_k < 1$ and $\sum_k s_k = 1$.

Any suggestions or references are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why the separate definitions for $i\neq j$ and $i=j$? They seem the same...

Comment: i \ne j is for off-diagonal terms, and i = j is for diagonal terms.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the form
$$\left(\sum_i a_i x_i\right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_i \frac{a_i}{s_i} x_i^2\right) \left(\sum_i a_i s_i\right). $$